# getting Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Tags: php

**Error:**

> Object of class `stdClass` could not be converted to `string` on line `$logQuery`

I am getting a silly error but not able to figure it out:

```
  $userName = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT username FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "users WHERE user_id = '" . (int)$user_id . "'");
```

storing value from other table so that I use it in another table:

```
 $logQuery = "insert into `" . DB_PREFIX . "user_activities` (user_id, product_id, action, data_values, time_of_action, ip_address, date_modified, username) values (" . $userId . "," . $product_id . ", 'update', '" . $updateData . "', NOW(),'" . $ipAddress . "', NOW(),'" . $userName . "')";

$this->db->query($logQuery);
```

Everything else is working fine but `$userName`.

Comment: @War10ck Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string on line $logQuery

Comment: What library does `query()` come from?  It returns an object so you need to fetch a column from it.  Try `var_dump($userName);`

Comment: @AbraCadaver tried dump it dont work

Comment: There's not enough code here to reproduce the problem.

Comment: _tried dump it dont work_ WHAT?  Didn't display anything?

Comment: @AbraCadaver ya nothing was displayed
I tried $userNamee = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT username FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "users WHERE user_id = '" . (int)$user_id . "'");
  $userName = json_decode(json_encode($userNamee),true);

it just stores array in the table

Comment: @Don'tPanic What are you missing? I need to get username of current user_id from different table and store it into user_activies table

Comment: Answering the questions @AbraCadaver asked would be a great start.

Comment: And... `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`